# why comparison did not return an int

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I am making simple Old Maid game. Here is my class for player's hand:

```
class OldMaidHand(Hand):
    def removeMatches(self):
        count=0;
        originalCards=self.cards[:];
        for card in originalCards:
            match=Card(3-card.suit,card.rank);
            if match in self.cards:
                self.cards.remove(card);
                self.cards.remove(match);
                print "Hand %s: %s matches %s "%(self.name,card,match);
                count=count+1;
            return count;`
```

but it's showing following error:

> `TypeError`:comparison did not return an int.

Here is my `__cmp__()` method in the `Card` class.

```
    def __cmp__(self,other):
        if self.suit>other.suit:
            return 1
        if self.suit<other.suit:
            return -1
        if self.rank>other.rank:
            return 1
        if self.rank<other.rank:
            return -1
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your class.

Comment: What if they're equal?

Comment: If none of your `if` clauses are True `__cmp__` will return `None`, which is not OK.

Comment: Along with the `==` condition, you could combine similar condition statements with an `or`

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist That should have been an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Don't post code in images.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for `__cmp__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__):

> Called by comparison operations if rich comparison (see above) is not defined. Should return a negative integer if self < other, zero if self == other, a positive integer if self > other.

In other words, as your error says, it should return an integer in any case.

If none of your if conditions obtain, your `__cmp__` will "fall off the end" of the function, returning `None` which is the default for any Python function which does not explicitly return something else. This is the source of your error (since `None` is not an integer).

I haven't examined your code too carefully but it seems you neglected the case where both the rank and suit are equal. Perhaps as a failsafe, you should simply `return 0` at the end of the function, unless you find a case where your conditions are unmet but the cards are inequal.

Comment: I missed the return value for __cmp__ method.After adding the return 0 it's working fine.